# How to derive wind variation equation in the planetary rotating atmosphere

Tags: atmosphere

[image]

In this picture is the equation of wind variation on rotating earth atmosphere. 
Does anyone know how to get this equation ? what is the basic idea ?
Thank you

Comment: Is there any way you can find a link to this so that people can read the whole thing?It would be helpful to know all the variables. How are the following defined? $q, A_{\omega}, \alpha, \delta, \omega_x, \omega_y$ It would be great to show that diagram at least. *Thanks!*

Comment: I second @uhoh's comment. We need more context to tell you what this is. On the first look, this looks like the rate of change of a position vector from a non-rotating into a rotating frame of reference.  The second term on the right-hand side of the equations looks like the coriolis force, although in weird notation. So it would definetly help to clarify the notation.